# Suppress Domino console message "error connecting to server ... the remote server..."

Tags: java, database, xpages, lotus-domino

I have an XPages app using Java backend that tries to access mail databases via session.getDatabase("foo", "bar"). My script is only to collect all mail files that the logged in user is able to access (caught via try-catch). But there is one issue:
If the server the script will be executed is not able to reach the other server the well known error message will occur in the log. The message doesn't come from the JVM so it is not caught by my try-catch so far. 
Is there a way to suppress this message? It is okay for me not to connect to that databases but I don't wanna get this message on the console. 
In production environment I cannot assure that the server has a connection document set up so if I cannot reach it, I'm fine with it.
Any ideas appreciated :)

Comment: Sneaky software? You could mitigate the possibilities by checking the connection and server documents and try low level Java to open the server. Like we do Telnet server 1352 to see if we can reach it

Comment: To be more specific: I'm trying to reach mail databases. For that it might be helpful to precheck connections documents etc. but the final opening (or not) depends on the user's rights given (or not) via delegation - though that might be trapped by try-catch. To check for a connection on socket 1352 may just say: "ah ok, the server is there" - but does not guarantee a connection from the Domino point of view. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you code runs on the server and from that code you can open the server using it's CN or the IP defined in the server document, then the Notes API should be able to do that too. (not fully sure if IP defined works - not the one you know, but the one in names.nsf - but it should)

Comment: You may play around with log related notes.ini parameters (see http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/2e73cbb2141acefa85256b8700688cea/4a262cb4418cbd3585256c1d0039cfb4?OpenDocument ). Though, I would strongly advise to not attempt and get rid of such messages. They may look annoying, but actually they are quite helpful for admins.

What you can do instead, is to rethink your application's logic and use what Domino server has to offer: Domain Catalog. See http://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeByDate/99C552E65FB1347D862570F1000DF8C6 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that the feature you are requesting Oliver is not possible.

The fact that you do not "generate/catch" the message in the JVM is due to the fact that the message is fired by the Notes engine itself (the core) and the JVM just hooks on it.

I have tried the NSPingServer C API as well to simulate your request and see if it would have not generated the error in the log but no luck there as well.

This is part of the core engine and any call you might do using standard LN functions will trigger this message.

If you have direct access to the servers (so no passthrugh) you might try to test if the port is reachable (via sockets) but this is way far too complicated in relation to the actual problem we are talking about.

I hope this helps in some way.

Cheers
Maurizio